# Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER

Tags: php, curl, php-7, php-curl

According to the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php) I should be able to use the CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER constant:

> CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER (integer)
>
> Available since PHP 7.0.7 and cURL7.37.0

But I get this error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER - assumed 'CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER'

My php version is:

> php -v
>
> PHP 7.1.0RC6 (cli) ( NTS )

I have php7.1-curl insalled.

My curl version is:

> curl --version
>
> curl 7.51.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.51.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8

Why can't I use the constant?

Edit: Added curl part of phpinfo:

```
curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.51.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => No
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => No
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => No
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => Yes
HTTP2 => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.1f
ZLib Version => 1.2.8
```

Comment: Show the curl section of phpinfo.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois added to question: http://pastebin.com/9vFi3pFQ

Comment: If you run `var_dump(CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER, PHP_VERSION);`, what do you get?

Comment: I get this `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER - assumed 'CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER' in ...php.php on line 3
string(19) "CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER"
string(8) "7.1.0RC6"`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois can you use the constant? Maybe it is a php bug

Comment: I can use the constant with PHP 7.0.13 - maybe because it's a RC it's not implementated yet (in that RC). The constant value is `10228`, so you can probably use the feature if you use the value directly (as workaround).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128752/discussion-between-clinical-and-charlotte-dunois).